# VS 2005 can't find .NET DLL class definitions even after Regasm

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2005

I have an unmanaged C++ project that uses a third-party .NET dll. It builds fine on one machine, but not on another--the IDE can't find the class definitions.

I ran `RegAsm.exe  TheLib.dll /codebase /tlb:TheLib.tlb`, and the registry entries on the two machines match. That is, even though the IDE says that `TheLib.Function()` is undefined, it's there in the registry on both machines.

What could I be doing wrong? (The source on the two machines is checked out of the same repository, and there are no uncommitted or unversioned files.)

Answer (score 1):

This can sometimes happen if you don't properly export classes or functions from your library.  Even though the code is there and it compiles fine when it links it may omit definitions or not actually generate exports to functions.  So then other projects importing the lib show them as being undefined.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/howto_export_cpp_classes.aspx#CppMatureApproach) describes a good way to export classes from a DLL and is worth a read as it could be related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've decommissioned that machine (for unrelated reasons), so I have no idea whether this would have solved the problem. Giving +1 anyway :)